# Proof That All Perfect Bayesian Equilibriums Are Subgame Perfect Nash Equilibriums

Tags: game-theory

My understanding is that all perfect bayesian equilibriums are also subgame perfect nash equilibriums. But, I've been unable to find a proof of this or prove it myself. Can anyone point me in the right direction on this front? Thank you.

Comment: If you look at the definitions of PBE and SPE you'll realize that all PBEs are indeed SPEs. Given a strategy profile and a consistent belief system, for it to be a PBE you need to check that there are no profitable deviations (according to the belief system) at any information set. Hence, in particular, you'll need to check that there are no profitable deviations in any subgame (which are determined by their root: an information set with only one node)

Comment: @Lorenzo thank you! What is an information set?

Comment: You can check any notes\books in game theory for that (or even wikipedia), it is a basic concept essential to define what a PBE is, let alone talk about it